# counting colums in csv file with python

Tags: python, function, csv, counting

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le696.png]

I want to count email accounts of male and female separately the code I wrote is not working properly so can anyone help me with this, please
here is my code thank you in advance

```py
    import csv

mailAcc = {}
femailAcc = {}

with open('1000 Records.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for i in csv_reader:
        email = i[6]
        gender = i[5]
        doman = email.split('@')[-1]
        if doman in mailAcc:
            if gender == 'm':
                 mailAcc[doman] = mailAcc[doman] + 1
        else:
            mailAcc[doman] = 1

        if doman in femailAcc:
            if gender == 'F':
                femailAcc[doman] = femailAcc[doman] + 1
        else:
            femailAcc[doman] = 1
            
    print('Mail Email accounts: ', mailAcc)
    print('Femail Email Accounts: ', femailAcc)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. please avoid using screenshots, copy& paste some dummy data as a [mcve]

On another note: I really hope that those email adresses are NOT real...

Comment: they are fake emails

Comment: As pointed by JoSste, please remove the screenshot and paste a sample of the input `CSV` file as pure text.

Comment: ok as your wish

Comment: Do you want just to count the total of male and female accounts or do you want to count them by domain? If you just want to count males and females, there is no need to check the domain.

Comment: I want to do this with domains like how many male accounts are Gmail and how much female accounts have a Gmail account. here male accounts are 9 but they are giving me more than 9 same with female accounts

Comment: Post the sample input data as text, please. It will make it easier for someone trying to help you reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that counts male and female accounts by domain using just standard Python modules:

```py
import csv
from collections import Counter

males = Counter()
females = Counter()

with open('1000 Records.csv') as f:
    records = csv.reader(f)
    for record in records:
        _, domain = record[6].split('@')
        gender = record[5]
        if gender.lower() == 'm':
            males.update((domain.lower(),))
        else:
            females.update((domain.lower(),))

    print('Total male accounts:', sum(males.values()))
    print('Total male accounts by domain')
    for k, v in males.items():
        print(k, v)

    print('Total female accounts:', sum(females.values()))
    print('Total female accounts by domain')
    for k, v in females.items():
        print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 1):

use pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_file.csv') # read in csv
df['domain'] = df['email'].apply(lambda x: x[x.index('@')+1:]) # column with just domain

male = {} # setup male dictionary
female = {} # setup female dictionary

# iterate on unique domains to get a count of male/female and populate in dictionaries
for domain in df['domain'].unique():   
    male[domain] = df[(df['gender']=='M') & (df['domain']==domain)].shape[0]
    female[domain] = df[(df['gender']=='F') & (df['domain']==domain)].shape[0]
```

Comment: I can't. it's not alow

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in `pandas`. As your columns are unnamed, use `header=None` when reading your `csv` and access the columns by number:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('1000 Records.csv', header=None)
df['mailhosts'] = df[6].str.split('@').str[-1]

gp = df.groupby(5)

#count e-mail accounts per gender:
print('Female Email Accounts:', gp.get_group('F')['mailhosts'].value_counts())
print('Male Email Accounts:', gp.get_group('M')['mailhosts'].value_counts())
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I can't use pandas because it not alow

Comment: @imhamza3333, if you can't use pandas, why did you mark this answer as accepted?