# count duplicat email addres with python in csv colum

Tags: python, csv, count, counting

```py
import csv
maleAcc = {}
femaleAcc = {}

with open('1000 Records.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
     csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
     for i in csv_reader:
         email = i[6]
         gender = i[5]
         domain = email.split('@')[-1]
         if gender.lower() == 'm' and domain in maleAcc:
             maleAcc[domain] = maleAcc[domain] + 1
         elif gender.lower() == 'm' and domain not in maleAcc:
             maleAcc[domain] = 1

         if gender.lower() == 'f' and domain in femaleAcc:
             femaleAcc[domain] = femaleAcc[domain] + 1
         elif gender.lower() == 'f' and domain not in femaleAcc:
             femaleAcc[domain] = 1

     print('Male Email accounts: ', maleAcc)
     print('FemaleEmail Accounts: ', femaleAcc)
```

with this code, I can count male and female email accounts separately. no, I want to do this with just gender value I will just check gender value and I get the same result can anyone help me with this thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [counting colums in csv file with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67107100/counting-colums-in-csv-file-with-python)

Comment: You already posted this same question before. Why repeat yourself? Just go to the original thread and discuss it further there.

Comment: this code will not count correctly.

Comment: ok sorry for this